# How do you keep scanner.next() from including newline?

Tags: java, io, newline, delimiter

I am trying to simply read words in a text file using scanner.next() with delimiter equal " " but the scanner includes the newline/carriage return with the token.

I have scoured the internet trying to find a good example of this problem and have not found it so I am posting it here. I can't find another similar problem posted here on SO. I also looked over the documentation on scanner and pattern (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) but I still cannot find a way to solve this.

**Text file:**

This is a test

to see if1 this, is working

ok!

**Code:**

```
int i = 0;
String string;
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
    scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
    string = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(i++ + ": " + string);
    }
}catch(IOException io_error) {
    System.out.println(io_error);
    }
```

**Output:**

0: This

1: is

2: a

3: test

to

4: see

5: if1

6: this,

7: is

8: working

ok!

As you can see, #3 and #8 have two words separated by a newline. (I know I can separate these into two separate strings.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation of Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says:

> The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by `Character.isWhitespace`

And the linked [documentation of `Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-) says:

> Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ('\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F').
> - It is '\t', U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
> - It is '\n', U+000A LINE FEED.
> - It is '\u000B', U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.
> - It is '\f', U+000C FORM FEED.
> - It is '\r', U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.
> - It is '\u001C', U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.
> - It is '\u001D', U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.
> - It is '\u001E', U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.
> - It is '\u001F', U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.

So, just don't set any specific delimiter. Keep the default, and newlines will be considered as a delimiter just like spaces, which means the token won't include newline characters.

Comment: That was painfully easy! I was over thinking it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After `string = scanner.next();` replace `\n` that is

```
string = string.replace("\n", "");
```

then print out the string variable .. 
That should do the trick

Comment: I added that line but I get the same output.

Comment: @Samuel read JB Nizet's answer, he is right i see now you have set the delimeter to " " instead set that as \n