# multiple line space seperated string input from user in java

Tags: java, string, console, user-input

I am trying a simple menu based accept and display string code in java.Here if I want to accept and display just a single string per line of input I am able to do with `next()`,but for space separated string as input I am not able to accept and display as intended.

this is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Trial
{
    String c,l;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Trial t=new Trial();
        int ch=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(ch!=3)
        {
            System.out.println("1.acc");
            System.out.println("2.dis");
            System.out.println("3.exit");
            System.out.println("enter ch");
            ch=Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("enter C");   
                    t.c=sc.nextLine();  

                    System.out.println("enter L");    
                    t.l=sc.nextLine();      
                    sc.nextLine();

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("c = "+t.c); 
                    System.out.println("l = "+t.l);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is the output that i am getting:

------------------------output------------

> 1.acc
>
> 2.dis
>
> 3.exit
>
> enter ch
>
> 1
>
> enter C
>
> enter L
>
> www eee
>
> rrr ttt
>
> 1.acc
>
> 2.dis
>
> 3.exit
>
> enter ch
>
> 2
>
> c =
>
> l = www eee

------------------output ends---------

whereas I want the output to be

> c = www eee" and l = "rrr ttt.

thanks

Comment: `nextline()` will read until the `\n`. Maybe you should try changing the [Scanner delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner)

Answer (score 1):

put `sc.nextLine()` after `ch=Integer.parseInt(sc.next());`

See this: [How do you keep scanner.next() from including newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669643/how-do-you-keep-scanner-next-from-including-newline)

Comment: ya it worked fine after adding nextLine() after next().thanx